# How can I remap my keyboard to create a lefthand numpad?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, xmodmap, xkb, remapping

Like many smaller machines, my laptop's keyboard is missing a dedicated numpad.

I can generally type without looking at my keyboard, but I am unable to blindly type numbers with the number row. That's why I thought of converting the left side of my keyboard into a second-level numpad (e.g. <kbd>Z</kbd> = <kbd>0</kbd>, <kbd>X</kbd> = <kbd>1</kbd>. <kbd>C</kbd> = <kbd>2</kbd>, <kbd>V</kbd> = <kbd>3</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd> = <kbd>4</kbd> and so on).

Another advantage would be the possiblity to quickly type numbers without taking the right hand off the mouse or moving the left hand across the entire keyboard.

Now I'm looking for a way to remap those keys to "create" the numpad, at best independent of the desktop environment, as I'm using multiple ones constantly. Also, it would be amazing if that mapping was portable, so I could set it up once and enable it for different keyboards/machines.

I know that it's possible to modify the keymap directly inside `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/`, but those allow only three modifiers (<kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>AltGr</kbd> (on European keyboards) and <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>AltGr</kbd>) and they're usually in use on the letter keys or require both hands to activate.

I thought of using either <kbd>Super_L</kbd> or a combination of <kbd>Shift_L</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> as modifier keys to access the numpad layer, since those combinations shouldn't be in use and are easy to reach with one hand.

How could this be accomplished?

Comment: Update: It's been a year since I opened this question and I've experimented a lot with AutoKey (v0.95). I'm getting used to the numpad and the "Phrases" allow the typing of numbers with shortcuts that can be set to the respective keys. Unfortunately, there are some issues with a few input fields that will not accept the numbers (e.g. the DuckDuckGo search). Also, I tried mapping my left Super key to both Super_L and Hyper_L, but it will still register Super-commands as well as typing the number on certain DEs. I'm still looking for a more elegant solution, maybe without the use of AutoKey?

Comment: I suggest whatever update to the OP, you post it in the question, noting it is an EDIT, instead of using a comment.

Answer (score 1):

I am into custom keyboards running QMK and such which allows to redefine every key and allows advanced behaviours such as layers. I recentley came across Kmonad which is a software tool which allows most of the same features. I haven't tried it myself, but this should allow you to hold down or toggle a key to activate a layer on which you can map numbers to the left side of the keyboard.

Here is a link to the github;
https://github.com/david-janssen/kmonad

I think Kmonad is also included in a lot of recent distros so it might already be available in APT.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the hint. It looks like quite a promising project. I actually thought something like this would already exist, given how many people thinker with their keyboard layouts. However, some issues: I couldn't find it in either the Ubuntu or Debian packages, also not in OpenSUSE. Also, according to their Github, the maintainer is currently unavailable. Since I can't build it on all my machines, I'd have to make myself a package to carry around, that's a little more maintenance than I'd like.

Answer (score 1):

You have already mentioned that you can edit `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/`, I think that this is the most portable option and the one that has worked for me in many linux distributions without needing to install anything. I found some issues in Android Studio but not with the numpad. Most software including browsers and DuckDuckGo work as intended.

If you are willing to give another try, I use <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> and the right hand for the numpad. I use the left hand for other keys like <kbd>Home</kbd>, <kbd>End</kbd>, <kbd>del</kbd>... and these are even more useful than the numpad for me.

Create a new language making a file like `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/aa` based on the language you normally use.

in the file `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.xml`

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.xml
```

before `</layoutlist>` add this text

```
<layout>
  <configItem>
    <name>aa</name>
    <shortDescription>Prototype700</shortDescription>
    <description>Prototype700</description>
    <languageList>
      <iso639Id>eng</iso639Id>
    </languageList>
  </configItem>
  <variantList/>
```

And choose that language as your default one. Below the one I use, based on `xkb/symbols/gb`

```
// based on a keyboard map from an 'xkb/symbols/gb' file

default  partial alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "Prototype700" {

    // Describes the differences between a very simple en_US
    // keyboard and a very simple U.K. keyboard layout defined by
    // Prototype700

    include "latin"

    name[Group1]="English (UK)";

    key <AE02>  { [         2,   quotedbl,  twosuperior,    oneeighth ] };
    key <AE03>  { [         3,   sterling, threesuperior,    sterling ] };
    key <AE04>  { [         4,     dollar,     EuroSign,   onequarter ] };

    key <AC11>  { [apostrophe,         at, dead_circumflex, dead_caron] };
    key <TLDE>  { [     grave,    notsign,          bar,          bar ] };

    key <BKSL>  { [numbersign, asciitilde,   dead_grave,   dead_breve ] };
    key <LSGT>  { [ backslash,        bar,          bar,    brokenbar ] };

    key <AD01> {    [     q,    Q,    Escape,       Adiaeresis ]    };
    key <AD02> {    [     w,    W,    Delete,            Aring ]    };
    key <AD03> {    [     e,    E,    Up,           Eacute ]    };
    key <AD04> {    [     r,    R,    Prior,       registered ] };
    key <AD05> {    [     t,    T,    Prior,            THORN ] };
    key <AD06> {    [     y,    Y       ]   };
    key <AD07> {    [     u,    U,    7,           Uacute ] };
    key <AD08> {    [     i,    I,    8,           Iacute ] };
    key <AD09> {    [     o,    O,    9,           Oacute ] };
    key <AD10> {    [     p,    P       ]   };
    key <AD11> {    [ bracketleft,  braceleft   ]   };
    key <AD12> {    [ bracketright, braceright  ]   };

    key <AC01> {    [     a,    A,    Home,           Aacute ]  };
    key <AC02> {    [     s,    S,    Left,          section ]  };
    key <AC03> {    [     d,    D,    Down,              ETH ]  };
    key <AC04> {    [     f,    F,    Right,                F ] };
    key <AC05> {    [     g,    G,    End,                G ]   };
    key <AC06> {    [     h,    H       ]   };
    key <AC07> {    [     j,    J,    4,                J ] };
    key <AC08> {    [     k,    K,    5,               OE ] };
    key <AC09> {    [     l,    L,    6,         Ooblique ] };
    key <AC10> {    [ semicolon,    colon,     ntilde,           Ntilde ]   };
    key <AC11> {    [ apostrophe,   quotedbl,  dead_acute, dead_diaeresis   ]   };

    key <AB01> {    [     z,    Z,    BackSpace,               AE ] };
    key <AB02> {    [     x,    X,    Insert,                X ]    };
    key <AB03> {    [     c,    C       ]   };
    key <AB04> {    [     v,    V,    Next,                V ]  };
    key <AB05> {    [     b,    B,    Next,                B ]  };
    key <AB06> {    [     n,    N,    0,           Ntilde ] };
    key <AB07> {    [     m,    M,    1,               mu ] };
    key <AB08> {    [     comma,    less, 2,           less ]   };
    key <AB09> {    [    period,    greater, 3,     greater ]   };
    key <AB10> {    [     slash,    question    ]   };

    include "level3(ralt_switch_multikey)"
};
```

If you use Windows machines, [Autohotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) is your friend. You probably know that, since you are familiar with [Autokey](https://github.com/autokey/autokey).

Comment: Thank you. I'm aware that using the ISO Level 3 layer is a possibility, it also does work on all input fields. However, I'd have to relocate some characters like `é` and `á`, which I may need sometimes. It would be even better if there was a possibility to add a 5th layer to the key mapping accessed with other modifier keys - any idea if this is possible at all? I have since edited my  `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc` file to make the left Super key (`LWIN`) call up `ISO_Level3_Shift`, basically turning it into a left-hand AltGr, but that doesn't solve the issue of the existing mappings.

Comment: PS: Thanks for mentioning how to add an additional language, I've always edited the original system files, but that's probably not very wise or stable and not all that portable.